# Issue with HTMLPurifier on href links staring with number

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I came across an issue with the PHP HTMLPurifier library. The issue I was facing was with the below input string

**<a href="http://1plusone/com/Update">Update</a>**

For the above input, I was getting the purified output as

**<a href="/com/Update">Update</a>**

I went through their documentations. But I was not able to find a solution for the issue.

**Source Code:**

```
require_once("/html_purifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php");
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$text= "<a href=\"http://1plusone/com/Update\">Update</a>";
$oPurifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$purifiedHtml= $oPurifier->purify($text);
echo $purifiedHtml;
```

I have also tried this [live demo](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter[AutoFormat.AutoParagraph]=0&filter[AutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI]=0&filter[AutoFormat.Linkify]=0&filter[AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty]=0&filter[AutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes]=0&filter[Null_CSS.AllowedProperties]=1&filter[Core.CollectErrors]=0&filter[Null_HTML.Allowed]=1&filter[Null_HTML.Doctype]=1&filter[HTML.SafeObject]=0&filter[HTML.TidyLevel]=medium&filter[URI.DisableExternalResources]=0&filter[Null_URI.Munge]=1&html=%3Ca%20href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2F1plusone%2Fcom%2FUpdate%22%3EUpdate%3C%2Fa%3E&submit=Submit) of htmlpurifier. It was also giving the same result.

Please help.

Comment: What is the code you are using to set up HTML Purifier?

Comment: Hi Edward, I have updated the source code. I was just using the default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that HTML Purifier rejects host names with only one part that have a leading digit.  The relevant code is in `HTMLPurifier/AttrDef/URI/Host.php`:

```
    // The productions describing this are:
    $a   = '[a-z]';     // alpha
    $an  = '[a-z0-9]';  // alphanum
    $and = "[a-z0-9-$underscore]"; // alphanum | "-"
    // domainlabel = alphanum | alphanum *( alphanum | "-" ) alphanum
    $domainlabel = "$an($and*$an)?";
    // toplabel    = alpha | alpha *( alphanum | "-" ) alphanum
    $toplabel = "$a($and*$an)?";
    // hostname    = *( domainlabel "." ) toplabel [ "." ]
    if (preg_match("/^($domainlabel\.)*$toplabel\.?$/i", $string)) {
        return $string;
    }
```

A simple fix would probably to patch this to be more permissive. I don't know if there is a more recent RFC that allows what you describe.